# Messed with nodes and composition. White screen renders. Anyone has a solution?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, uv-image-editor

i know this is kinda my fault but i'm a rookie and got messed up with composition and trying to edit a render results' color and contrast and all went downhill from there. Can someone help me correct the render settings so i cannot get white images anymore? [the file here](https://we.tl/K14s4f1euv)

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't have a render layers node in your node tree, that's why you didn't have any render at all. It's the main input of the render tree. (I also added a file output node, but it's not required)
[image: node tree with render layers]